# me pueden explicar los metodos get_context_data y get_queryset

Tags: python, django

Me gustaria obtener una explicacion lo suficientemente explicita, la documentación con django es excelente pero en algunos caso un poco confusa, me gustaria sabe como usar ambos metodos y un caso practico si se pudiera.

Gracias

Comment: disculpa acabo de visualizar tu comentario, no estaba al tanto de esto, ya reviso los manuales para formular preguntas, de hecho acabo de hacer una y por lo que mencionas no cumple los parametros, para editarla voy a requerir leer los manuales, disculpe...

Answer (score 2):

### get_context_data

como su nombre indica obtiene los datos del contexto. Son los datos, variables, objectos, etc, que le vas a pasar al template para maquetarlos. Por ejemplo es donde pasarías un formulario en caso de que necesites un template con 2 o más formularios.

te pongo un ejemplo de como funcionaria:

```
class TemplateDetalle(DetailView):
    model = ModelTemplate
    form_class = TemplateForm
    template_name = "backend/template/templatedetalle.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('templates')

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(TemplateDetalle, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['grupo'] = self.request.user.groups.get().name
        context['form2'] = TemplateForm2()
        return context
```

### get_queryset

Esta función es la que se encarga de obtener los objetos del modelo que le indicas en la variable model de tu clase. Ésta función por defecto obtiene el queryset de la llamada `model.objects.all()`. Puedes reescribir esta función de la misma manera que `get_context_data()` para indicar alguna restrincción especial que necesites en esa view.

Añado un ejemplo y lo explico:

```
def get_queryset(self,perfil,npagina=1):
    consulta = Producto.objects.filter(Q(perfil = perfil), Q(estado_rev=4)|Q(estado_rev=6)).order_by('-f_act')
    lista_productos = []
    for p in consulta:
        foto = Foto.objects.filter(producto = p.id)
        lista_productos.append({'producto':p,'foto':foto[0],'contador_like':contador_like(p)})
    paginacion = Paginator(lista_productos,80)
    if len(paginacion.page(1)) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return paginacion.page(npagina)
```

En este ejemplo estoy obteniendo todos los objetos del modelo Producto filtrando por la consulta que puedes ver y obteniendo otros datos relacionados como el contador de "likes" para crear páginas. De esta manera no obtienes todos los productos que existen ya que eso podría generar una carga muy pesada para el servidor. De está manera utilizando la función `get_contenxt_data` puedes añadirle la linea `context['productos']=self.get_queryset(npagina=self.request.GET.get('page'),perfil=perfil)` y en tu template tendrías la variable `{{productos}}` que contendría una lista de 80 objetos.

Comment: sin duda una gran respuesta, seria un plus poner un ejemplo de get_queryset

Comment: Lo edito ahora mismo y añado un ejemplo

Comment: muchisimas gracias por tan excelente aporte. la verdad soy nuevo en el foro y estoy aprendiendo django, de hecho estoy enamorado del framework, me gusta estudiarlo bastante, considero que he aprendido muchisimo pero es mucho mas lo que debo aprender. Gracias por el aporte

Comment: cualquier duda que tengas puedes preguntar y estaré encantado de contestar. de nada.